# Making graphic object selected

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi i want to make my graphic object "selected" after click on them.

I tryied something like that to make selected line:

```
else if (e.OriginalSource is Line)
        {
            LineFocus = true;
            MojaLinia = (Line)e.OriginalSource;

            Rectangle rect_1 = new Rectangle
            {
                Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                StrokeThickness = 1,
                Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255))
            };
            rect_1.Width = 6;
            rect_1.Height = 6;

            Canvas.SetLeft(rect_1, MojaLinia.X1);
            Canvas.SetTop(rect_1, MojaLinia.Y1);
            canvas.Children.Add(rect_1);
            Rectangle rect_2 = new Rectangle
            {
                Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                StrokeThickness = 1,
                Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255))
            };
            rect_2.Width = 6;
            rect_2.Height = 6;

            Canvas.SetLeft(rect_2, MojaLinia.X2);
            Canvas.SetTop(rect_2, MojaLinia.Y2);
            canvas.Children.Add(rect_2);
        }
```

Its a bit stupid, and its hard to make white rectangle with distance from line. Is there any good way to do this without tons of if() ?

Im using VS2012, WPF/C# .

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx) to show your shape as "selected", this way you can also make the "selected" state visual hint in XAML.

And you can use an [Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) to "add" a `IsSelected` property (boolean for example) to your object and toggle the value each time there is a click event rised.